# String Manipulation in C, <optimized out> error

Tags: c, string, webserver, cs50

I was solving cs50x pset6 Webserver problem and I would be very grateful if someone could help me.
Can anyone explain what is happenning below in gdb(also in source code itself) please?

[Optimized out and Gone String Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6VmI.png)

The problem is that manipulation string variables is needed in this problem set, but somehow I lose them whenever new variable comes up(along).

I tried compiling differently as suggested by some sources e.g. https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/variable-optimized-out-eventhough-it-will-be-used-later .

But nothing has changed even I tried other solutions.

So guys I will appreciate if you can help me to fix this issue.

Here is my source code(lines 151-391): http://codepaste.net/2uipag

Edit: This error is affecting not just debugging mode, but the program itself    isn't giving intended result. Basically:

- Line ="GET /cat.html HTTP/1.1"
- absolute_path="/cat.html" (extracted using strncpy())
- root="/home/jharvard/pset6/public"
- path= root along with absolute_path (strcat())

Because absolute_path is optimized out instead of getting "home/jharvard/pset6/public/cat.html" for path variable, I am getting "home/jharvard/pset6/public"

I apologize for being unclear and thank you for assistance.

Comment: You should factorize some of this code, `strncpy` is very error prone, you seem to use it correctly, but it would be safer to use a utility function that copies a string into a fixed length buffer, truncating if necessary, such as BSD's `strlcpy()` or your own.  This would  avoid replicated expressions and thus potential sources of inconsistencies.

Comment: Local variables may not be available to the debugger because they may live in transient registers or share stack space if the compiler can determine it is safe and useful to do so.  What is the actual problem? What observed behavior is not what you expect? What did you expect?

Comment: The code paste referenced no longer exists (2016-08-28).  This question serves no useful purpose on SO any more.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say what is happening with any specificity, but most likely,  at some point after the last use of your `line` pointer by the function, the optimized version of the program re-uses its storage for something else.  If the variable is still in scope at that point then *in principle* you should still be able to examine its value, but if your program in fact does not examine its value then it makes no difference in program behavior.  Except as viewed via a debugger.

If you intend to run your code in a debugger then it is best to compile it (for that purpose) with optimization disabled (option `-O0` for many C compilers, including `gcc`).  After you have worked out the problems, compile your final program with whatever optimization level you deem appropriate.

Comment: The OP should already be compiling in debug mode, as suggested on cs50.

Comment: @chqrlie, Well yes, he should, but whether in fact he is not or whether his compiler is buggy, some amount of optimization is evidently being performed.  The solution is still to compile with all optimization disabled, even if that requires using a different compiler.

Comment: I agree, I was hoping he would confirm.  Even with `-O0` the compiler may still either optimize or forget to generate full debug information.  Switching to a different compiler is a good suggestion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried compiling before with optimization off including gcc, unfortunately it didn't help. Not just running in debugger, but also compiling   file is not giving desired execution. Because of string variables get optimized out I am getting segmentation fault unable to reach old ones.